# PHP's inet_pton() to Convert both IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: php

When I use `inet_pton()` for `FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329` I get `������)` whatever that is.

So then I added `bin2hex()` and get this `fe800000000000000202b3fffe1e8329` better.

However, I was expecting a string of 16 not 32.

And it gets even more inconsistent from there.

When converting `8.8.8.8` I get `08080808` string of 8.

---

Is there a way to achieve some consistency where everything is the same length or should I add this to the database as is?

Am looking for an efficient/fast way to accomplish this that will result in a smaller string which would take less space on my database, without too many resources being wasted at it.

Answer (score 6):

An IPv6 address is 128 bits long; an IPv4 address is 32 bits long.

This is no accident: one of the key motivations for creating IPv6 was that there are not enough possible 32-bit addresses for the needs of the modern internet.

> `������)` whatever that is.

That is 128 bits, or 16 bytes, of binary data. Attempting to view it as text won't give you anything very interesting, because not every combination of bits is a displayable character.

> So then I added `bin2hex()` and get this `fe800000000000000202b3fffe1e8329`

Converting the binary string to hexadecimal means representing each set of 4 bits as a character from the set `0123456789abcdef`. The result is a string which is human readable, but 32 characters long (128 / 4 = 32).

You might notice that the standard way of writing an IPv6 address is just this string with a `:` added every 4 characters for readability.

> When converting 8.8.8.8 I get 08080808

In binary, an IPv4 address would be 32 bits, or 4 bytes, long; but again, those wouldn't all be printable characters. As hexadecimal, it is a string 8 characters long, because that is how many sets of 4 bits it contains (32 / 4 = 8).

> Is there a way to achieve some consistency where everything is the same length

The only way to make IPv4 addresses and IPv6 addresses the same length is to pad the IPv4 addresses with something on the left. It's like saying "can I make John's name take up the same space as Samantha's".

> Am looking for an efficient/fast way to accomplish this that will result in a smaller string which would take less space on my database

The shortest universal representation is the binary one you got from `inet_pton` in the first place; just make sure to store it in a binary column in your database, not `VarChar`/`Text`/etc.

Alternatively, the standard text format for IPv6 has a short-hand where one sequence of 0s in an address can be replaced by `::`, so `FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329` can be abbreviated `FE80::0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329`. I don't know of a PHP function for making such abbreviations, but it wouldn't be too hard to write one.

If you need it to be human-readable but short, you could play with other human-readable encodings of binary, like Base64 (which is [natively supported by PHP](http://php.net/base64_encode)). A character in base64 represents 6 bits, but the string is conventionally padded to be a multiple of both 8 and 6 bits long, so an IPv6 address will take up 24 printable characters (128 bits + 16 bits padding / 6 = 24).

Other rarer encodings are possible, such as "[Base85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85)", which use a wider range of characters to make the output shorter. However, they're all mathematically guaranteed to be longer than the binary representation, so you'll always need at least 16 bytes.

Comment: Well heres the thing...I'm only upgrading the apps one at a time to have them IPv6 compatible. The other apps use IPv4 only and `ip2long()`. So this would utilize the same column...it would just be a string instead of an integer like ip2long. Is there any way to get a more compact hex especially in regards to the ipv6 address?

Comment: @Borsn no. you can't pack a 128 bit IPv6 address into the space of a 32 bit IPv4 address. Ever. At all. There's also not a "more compact hex", there's the binary representation. Read this answer again.

Comment: @Borsn As Sammitch says, there's no such thing as "a more compact hex" - hexadecimal always represents 4 bits per character. However, I've edited a section into my answer about base64 and similar, which you might find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should save them as they since these both are 2 different things. Even if both are designed for the same purpose.

Still if you want to get these both along you would most Likely take these actions :
* calculate the decimal value of the ipv6 since it's hexadecimal or the other way around.
* ipv6 is 2^128 and ipv4 is 2^32. You need to calculate the differences to have the same base on both sides. This could be accomplished with placeholders (zeros at the start as example) until you have the same Potency
*You now could save them as even strings in the databases.

I sadly can't give examples since I'm on my mobile phone. But I think it should be clear.